# DC voltage ripple help

Tags: voltage-regulator, audio, dc, dc-dc-converter, ripple

I am new here and I realy need your help. For diplome at the end of my studying I am making the audio amplifier module (power amplifier, preamplifier, tone control, power supply, linear regulator) all in one. A have almost everythink work yust can solve noisy hum in preamplifier (TL082) that is caused by DC power supply ripple. I put pi filter CRCRC (1k Ohm, 20 uF) before linear regulator to filter DC voltage from power amplifier and get pretty good symetrical voltage, but with 100 Hz noise at both voltages. How can I get rid of that 100 Hz ripple?

I am using LM337 and LM317 to voltage drop from 40 V to 18 V and that ripple also copy to the output of the linear regulator and causes hum in sound. Just for information, the power amplifier work great alone and also preamplifier work great with external DC power supply from professional power supply device.

[image]

[image]

Comment: _"noisy hum in preamplifier (TL082) that is caused by dc power supply ripple"_ What brings you to this conclusion? Also, show schematic.

Comment: 1 megohm series resistors before the regulator? I doubt that very much. A schematic is really needed.

Comment: Show your schematic. Have you followed the datasheet recommendations on the LM337 output caps in particular?

Comment: 1 ohm and 10,000 uF have 0.01 second tau, or 16 Hertz F3dB, giving about 2 octaves of filtering of 60Hz ripple, or only 12dB attenuation. If you can have 10 ohms in the preamplifier VDD path, you'll get 20dB (10X) more ripple reduction, or 32 dB total.

Comment: Hi guys thanks for help, I attach an schematich of power supply smoothing.

Comment: @winny The preamplifier work totally normal with power amplifier when is powered by power supply from rigol before the linear regulators. But when i connect the power supply before linear regulators from network voltage or from preamplifier there is always 100Hz hum in sound. I think that I need just a good filer before lineare regulators.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Hi elliot, sory for my mistake, it's a 1k Ohm resistor. I add you shematic.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany yes, I test capacitors from 1uF to 4000uF and its olways the same, some times even worse. I think that I need to add an LC filter and the input of LM's but i have no experience with it.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf Hi, thanks for help but adding an extra 10000uF capacitors is not possible. Preamplifier spend less than 0.1A, what do you think with adding LC filtering to reduce ripple ?. I also made self circuit with diode bridge and crcrc filter only for testing and its the same ripple and noise as I the power supply out of poweramplifier and reduced to 18V.

Comment: It sounds like you might have an earth loop. This is typically caused by mains earth connections on each device followed by an audio GND connection between the pre-amp and the power amp. See if you can disconnect the screen on the input to the power amp (if there is GND connection via the mains earths).

Comment: You are changing several things when moving from stabilized DC power supply to your AC source so you can’t narrow it down to op-amp supply ripple from that. Also, MEASURE your supply ripple and compare with PSRR in the datasheet. Show layout!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ground may well be the issue. But since that's layout dependent I have a couple of other suggestions.

Parallel each of the rectifier diodes with 10nF. And isolate the supplies from the power rails with diodes (one for the positive, one for the negative). And make sure there is only one ground wire from the preamp supply to the rest of the circuit.

Comment: I am curious about that unfinished line from Gnd to preamp. Is it really not there? And if it is there then I am pretty sure there will be another one from preamp to power amp somewhere down the line, since they are drawn as independent modules.

Answer (score 2):

**I solved the problem.** Hum from preamplifier has been partly removed by RC filter on the linear regulators input (1000uF and 1000kOhm) on both voltages and the other part of hum was removed by removing grounding loop. Problem with grounding was because i took ground just after power supply circuit before power amplifier, but I should take it after power amplifier like i did now and work perfect. Thank you for all advices.